# Identification fan control

Tags: electrical

I need to replace this entire component. It is a dial that controls the speed of a fan built into a fireplace.

What am I looking at? What should I look for when buying a replacement?

[image: front]
[image: side]
[image: back]

Comment: Much more information is needed such as how it is wired and just what it controls or is it part of a control system. Since that company is in Belgium, you may need a whole new control system. I tried putting the numbers into their search bar but that provided no results from them. .

Comment: Your first step should be to contact the manufacturer of the fireplace and see if they have repair parts available.  Failing that, a motor/fan speed controller is a fairly common item.  You may be able to locate something that will work with some homework.

Comment: Have you gone to dvc-co.com and looked up model `1324` or `00AR00 AA` or `0137`? Have you done a general web search for any of those (possible) model numbers and "Jide"?

Comment: Yes I searched their website and google and couldn't find anything.it doesn't suprise me, since the fireplace is pretty old. It was built way before I bought the house and have no documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be a solid state speed controller.
On my side of the pond they don’t have the built in fuse.
If you purchase a locally sourced solid state speed controller that has 1.6 amp capability or more you should be fine.